# 7-segment 4-digit display ghosting

Tags: adc, multiplexer, 7segmentdisplay, atmega328p

Currently I'm tinkering with my ADC project with my ATmega328. I asked  my microcontroller educator how I can fix this issue with the ghosting. I thought it had something to do with frequency or the 2N2222 transistors, but he said something about my code not being optimized and didn't give me any clue of where I could start.

Can I get some help?

[image]

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// Definir los valores de los segmentos para mostrar dígitos en el display de 7 segmentos
int seg7_1[10] = {0x3F, 0x06, 0x5B, 0x4F, 0x66, 0x6D, 0x7D, 0x07, 0x7F, 0x67};

// Inicializar el ADC
void ADC_init()
{
ADMUX = (1 << REFS0); // AVCC con un condensador externo en el pin AREF
ADCSRA = (1 << ADEN) | (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0); // Habilitar el ADC, prescaler de 8
}

// Leer el valor del ADC
uint16_t read_ADC(uint8_t channel)
{
ADMUX = (ADMUX & 0xF0) | (channel & 0x0F); // Seleccionar el canal ADC con una máscara de seguridad
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC); // Iniciar la conversión
while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC)); // Esperar a que la conversión se complete
return ADC;
}

// Suavizar el valor del ADC
uint16_t smooth_ADC(uint8_t channel)
{
static uint16_t readings[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
uint32_t sum = 0;

// Desplazar las lecturas
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    readings[i] = readings[i + 1];
    sum += readings[i];
}

// Tomar una nueva lectura
readings[3] = read_ADC(channel);
sum += readings[3];

// Calcular el promedio
return sum / 4;
}

int main(void)
{
// Configurar los pines de salida
DDRB = 0xFF; // 1111 1111
DDRD = 0xF0; // 1111 0000
DDRC &= ~(1 << PC0); // Configurar PC0 como entrada
PORTC |= (1 << PC0); // Habilitar pull-up en PC0

// Inicializar el ADC
ADC_init();

while (1)
{
    // Obtener el valor suavizado del ADC desde PC0
    uint16_t adc_value = smooth_ADC(0);
    

    // Separar el valor en dígitos individuales
    int i, j, k, z;
    i = adc_value % 10;
    j = (adc_value / 10) % 10;
    k = (adc_value / 100) % 10;
    z = (adc_value / 1000) % 10;

    // Mostrar los dígitos en el display de 7 segmentos
    PORTD |= 1 << PORTD4;
    PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD5) & ~(1 << PORTD6) & ~(1 << PORTD7); // 0100
    PORTB = seg7_1[z];
    _delay_ms(1);

    PORTD |= 1 << PORTD5;
    PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD6) & ~(1 << PORTD7) & ~(1 << PORTD4); // 0010
    PORTB = seg7_1[k];
    _delay_ms(1);

    PORTD |= 1 << PORTD6;
    PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD7) & ~(1 << PORTD4) & ~(1 << PORTD5); // 0001
    PORTB = seg7_1[j];
    _delay_ms(1);

    PORTD |= 1 << PORTD7;
    PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD4) & ~(1 << PORTD5) & ~(1 << PORTD6); // 1000
    PORTB = seg7_1[i];
    _delay_ms(1);
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should add a schematic or circuit diagram to your question.

Answer (score 7):

You are turning two digits on at once by writing the 'or' first and then the &. The new one will have the segment drive for the old one on for a short period of time- enough to create perceptible light.

It would be better to turn the segment drive off first, then manipulate the digit drive, then write the new segment drive, but maybe you could get acceptable performance by just reversing the order of each pair of PORTD assignment statements. That's because decreasing the brightness of a segment slightly is nowhere near as visually perceptible as light where there should be none (due to logarithmic  -like eye response).